# Python3 button can't be deleted

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, dictionary, tkinter

To make long story short, I've made dictionary filled with buttons that call a function with parameters (the coordinates which they are in) like this:

```
for m in range(75, 86):
    for n in range(75, 86):
        x=Button(win, text=" ", command=lambda m=m, n=n: click(m, n))
        x.grid(row=m, column=n)
        buttons[(n, m)]=x
```

I want to delete the called button (which in this case is the pressed button), but somehow it keeps deleting other buttons. The function that should delete the buttons is this:

```
def click(p, q):
    global buttons
    buttons[(p, q)].destroy()
```

Can anybody help tell what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indexing the button in the buttons array as `(n, m)`, but destroying the button as `(m, n)`. Decide if you are using column-first or row-first notation and then use that consistently!

If you can't do that, use `(row, column)` or at least `(r, c)` instead of meaningless `(m, n)` or `(p, q)`